# usage of promise with while loop results in freezing ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, while-loop, async-await, es6-promise

I am trying to replace async/await with promise (while preserving the logic/purpose/outcome of the code) but struggling to understand the problem resulting upon usage of promise. When I attempt to execute new version of the code using promise browsers freezes and seems to be executing infinite loop. Could you please help me to understand what the problem is?

Here is the working state of the code using async/await

```
async fetchNewJokes() {
let newJokes = [];

while (newJokes.length < 10) {
  const {data} = await   axios.get('https://icanhazdadjoke.com/', {
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
    },
  });
  newJokes.push(data.joke);
 
}

this.setState({
    jokes: newJokes,
  });

}
```

Here is the attempted replacement of async await with promise

```
fetchNewJokes() {
let newJokes = [];

while (newJokes.length < 10) {
  axios.get('https://icanhazdadjoke.com/', {
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
    },
  }).then({data}=>{
  newJokes.push(data.joke);
 })
  
}
this.setState({
    jokes: newJokes,
  })
}
```

Comment: _"Could you please help me to understand what the problem is?"_ - Try to understand what `await` does

Comment: "*I am trying to replace async/await with promise*" - `async`/`await` is based on promises. You seem to be trying to replace `await` with `.then()`.

Comment: @Bergi could you please elaborate on your comment?

Answer (score 2):

First of all we have to understand that JS is single threaded. Just one thread processes the code of your program. It can run only one piece of the code (lets say function) at a time. So keeping this fact in mind lets try to find out whats going on in  your code.

```
async fetchNewJokes() {
    let newJokes = [];

    while (newJokes.length < 10) {
        /*1*/ const {data} = await axios.get('https://icanhazdadjoke.com/', {
          headers: {Accept: 'application/json'}});
        /*2*/newJokes.push(data.joke);
        this.setState({jokes: newJokes});
    }
}
```

JS performs this function until it meets `await` on line `\*1*\`. Then it executes `axios.get()` and returns to the main code without waiting of result of `axios.get()`.

Further it continues working with other code doing other useful things like rendering, processing user input and so on. *At time to time it checks* whether `axios.get()` finished or not.

When `axios.get()` finished it assign result to `data` value and continues performing this function from line `\*2*\`. On the next iteration of `while` loop it meets `await` again and repeat actions described above. And the same happens for every step of `while` loop.

Now lets look at the second code snippet.

```
fetchNewJokes() {
    let newJokes = [];

    while (newJokes.length < 10) {
        axios.get('https://icanhazdadjoke.com/', {
          headers: {Accept: 'application/json'}}).then(()=>{
            newJokes.push(data.joke);
            this.setState({jokes: newJokes});
        });
    }
}
```

JS performs this function and executes `axios.get()`. Now to execute `.then()` JS has to check at time to time whether `axios.get()` finished or not. But it can not!

JS thread is busy by performing `while` loop. You don't give it a time to do anything else. It continues to call `axios.get()` again and again without any possibility to check result. Furthermore since JS busy by doing the loop it doesn't have time for rendering. Loop consumes more and more resources. That's why browser freezes.

So what a solution? @gdh already gave you one of them. But if you need to make less changes to your code, just don't rely on result of `Promise` in the condition of the loop.

```
fetchNewJokes() {
    for (let i=0; i<10; i++) {
        axios.get('https://icanhazdadjoke.com/', {
          headers: {Accept: 'application/json'}}).then(()=>{
            this.setState({jokes: this.state.jokes.concat(data.joke)});
        });
    }
}
```

In this case the function executes `axios.get()` ten times and returns control to the main code.

Comment: спасибо за развернутый ответ. Получается await позволяет высвободиться из цикла на короктий период и приступить к выполнению дальнейшего кода, в то время как .then() сдерживает выполнение дальнейшего кода?

Comment: @esentai да, await высвобождает из цикла и позволяет выполнить дальнейший код. .then() сработает только тогда, когда JS проверит и убедится, что вызов axios.get() выполнен. Но такая проверка тоже требует времени. А цикл не прекращается и времени на проверку нет. Выполнение кода сдерживает не then(),  а бесконечный цикл. А бесконечный он, потому что инкремент находится в then(). Замкнутый круг.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, don't set state inside while loop unless you need to. Your async/await code worked coz the state updates are batched and the state is updated when the enclosing scope execution is finished (which is while loop).

In your promise code the state is set in then block. So the component is re-rendered after each api call and seems like `fetchNewJokes` again and so on.

So use `Promise.all` to solve the issue.

**Like this**

```js
const fetchNewJokes = () => {
  let promiseArr = [];
  const counter = 0;

  while (counter < 10) {
    promiseArr.push(
      axios
        .get("https://icanhazdadjoke.com/", {
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
          },
        })
        .then((data) => {
          //   newJokes.push(data.joke);
          return data.joke;
        })
    );
    counter++;
  }
  Promise.all(promiseArr).then((newJokes) => {
    this.setState({
      jokes: newJokes,
    });
  });
};
```